# Testing angular auth guard redirection

Tags: angular, jasmine, jasmine2.0, spyon

I have an Angular `authenticated` guard

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {
    constructor(@Inject('Window') private window: Window,
                private readonly authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {}

    canActivate(): boolean {
        if (!this.authenticationService.isAuthenticated) {
            this.window.location.href = '/login';
        }
        return allowed;
    }

    canActivateChild(): boolean {
        return this.canActivate();
    }
}
```

And I have these tests with a mock window I am injecting so that my test windoe doesn't redirect and so I can check to see if the `href` is set

```js
const MockWindow = {
    location: {
        _href: '',
        set href(url: string) {
            //console.log('set!', url)
            this._href = url;
        },
        get href(): string {
            //console.log('get!', this._href)
            return this._href;
        }
    }
};

describe('Guard: authenticated', () => {
    let redirectSpy: jasmine.Spy;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                AuthenticatedGuard,
                AuthenticationService,
                {provide: 'Window', useValue: MockWindow}
            ]
        });
        redirectSpy = spyOnProperty(MockWindow.location, 'href', 'set');
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    });

    it('should allow route activation when both the token is set', inject([AuthenticatedGuard], (guard: AuthenticatedGuard) => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'foo');
        expect(guard.canActivate()).toEqual(true);
        expect(guard.canActivateChild()).toEqual(true);
        expect(redirectSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));

    it('should disallow route activation when the token is not set', inject([AuthenticatedGuard], (guard: AuthenticatedGuard) => {
        expect(guard.canActivate()).toEqual(false);
        expect(guard.canActivateChild()).toEqual(false);
        expect(redirectSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login'); //<-- this fails!
    }));

...
```

The `expect(redirectSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/login');` always fails saying it was never called at all.  Same with just `expect(redirectSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();` - What am I doing wrong here? I want to be able to test this redirection, but I don't want my karma test browser to actually redirect.

(FYI: I need to use `window.location.href` instead of the angular router so we can direct users to a different non-angular application that handles the login)

Comment: Yes, see the last sentence in the above question.  i need to direct to a URL outside of angular.  We have an MVC app that handles the authentication (and other things), and then this angular application sits inside of it at the `site.com/app/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found something that works which removes the need for a spy.  now I just `get` the injected window provider from the guard by calling `TestBed.get('Window')` which seems to work great!

Please let me know if this could be done better!

```js
const MockWindow = {
    location: {
        href: '',
    }
};

describe('Guard: authenticated', () => {
    let guard: AuthenticatedGuard;
    let guardWindow: Window;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                AuthenticatedGuard,
                AuthenticationService,
                {provide: 'Window', useValue: MockWindow}
            ]
        });
        guardWindow = TestBed.get('Window');
        MockWindow.location.href = '/some/page';
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
    });

    it('should allow route activation when the token is set', () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'foo');
        expect(guard.canActivate()).toEqual(true);
        expect(guard.canActivateChild()).toEqual(true);
        expect(guardWindow.location.href).toEqual('/some/page');
    });

    it('should disallow route activation when the token is not set', () => {
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', 'foo');
        expect(guard.canActivate()).toEqual(false);
        expect(guard.canActivateChild()).toEqual(false);
        expect(guardWindow.location.href).toEqual('/login');
    });
...
```